# Unable to display polish characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

This may look like a duplicate but I've been searching for hours and none of the suggested fixes for similar problems are working:

I have text in xls file that was converted to CSV.  It contains polish characters.  I've confirmed I did save as UTF8 encoded.  I don't have access to PHPMyAdmin on this server, so I uploaded this UTF8 encoded CSV file to the server.

I then use a UTF8 encoded PHP file to load the database up:

```
        mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pl_PL.UTF-8");
    require_once('config.php');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $f=fopen('questions-final2.csv','r');
    $questions=array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //$num = count($data);
      //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
      print_r($data);
        $questions[]=$data;
        //mysql_query('INSERT INTO questions(question_id,text,answer_time,difficulty,mode) VALUES '.implode(',',$inserts));
      //echo $data;
    }

    //exit();
// import of questions  
    $prev_index=0;
    foreach($questions as $index=>$question){
        if($index>0)
            if($question[0]==$questions[$prev_index][0])
                unset($questions[$index]);
            else
                $prev_index=$index;     
    }

    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    mysql_query('SET NAME utf8');   

    $res=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM questions');

    $inserts=array();
    foreach($questions as $question)
        $inserts[]='("'.$question[5].'","'.addslashes($question[1]).'","'.$question[7].'","'.$question[0].'","'.$question[4].'")';

    mysql_query('INSERT IGNORE INTO questions(question_id,text,answer_time,difficulty,mode) VALUES '.implode(',',$inserts));

    var_dump(mysql_error());

    fclose($f);
```

Now, here is what the database says:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can't get that latin1 part to go away.  My my.conf looks like this:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I'm using putty and have confirmed I have it set to utf8 encoding as well, this is the output:

```
mysql> select text from questions limit 1;
+-------------------------------------------+
| text                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
| ?wi?to Unii Europejskiej obchodzone jest: |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the original text as it should appear:

```
Święto Unii Europejskiej obchodzone jest:
```

Also I have tried :

```
alter table questions modify column text TEXT character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
alter table questions convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Both before and after importing data, to no avail.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query('SET NAME utf8');
```

This query should trigger an error:

> SQL Error (1193): Unknown system variable 'NAME'

... but you don't see it because you don't test whether `mysql_query()` succeeds. [The correct variable is `NAMES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//set-statement.html#idp97550880).

Comment: Thank you kind sir!  Wow.  I can't believe the problem was that simple. Never again will I forget the importance of proper error checking.

Comment: @Sebas - As far as I know, PHP doesn't read `my.conf` to find settings.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, yes of course, but doesn't mysql load it automatically then? This is not a php setting.

Comment: @Sebas - That's a *client* setting. The client is PHP. Thus it's a PHP setting.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I see, so from my understanding it should not even exist in the my.cnf file, am I correct?

Comment: @Sebas - Honestly, no idea about whether it works or not. From the PHP perspective it's better to set your options explicitly rather than relying on server-side defaults. Reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) if you're inclined to do some testing.

Comment: Thanks for the link: `The content of init_connect is not executed for users that have the SUPER privilege` So basically any root connection will skip this parameter, that might be the reason why it didn't work in his case.